# Find Body in calendar item

Tags: python, calendar, outlook-2010, win32com

I'm trying to create a Python (2.7) script that searches outlook calendar items for certain words in the item body.

This is the search term I have at the moment:

```
someCalendar.Items.Find("[Body] = 'Some words'")
```

And this is the error message:

```
File "<COMObject <unknown>>", line 2, in Find
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (4096, u'Microsoft Outlook', u'The operation failed.', None, 0, -2147221246), None)
```

I can successfully search Subject, Location, Start, and End, but when I try to search Body it raises that error.  Tried using [Message] instead of [Body] and this removes the error but fails to find my test calendar item.

Answer (score 0):

The `Body` property can't be used for the `Find`/`FindNext` or `Restrict` methods of the `Items` class. Try using the `RTFBody` instead. Be aware, a folder object may contain different type of items, so the `RTFBody` property can be asent on some of them. See [Filtering Items Using a String Comparison](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/outlook-vba/articles/filtering-items-using-a-string-comparison) for more information.

Also you may consider using the [Application.AdvancedSearch](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/outlook-vba/articles/application-advancedsearch-method-outlook) method.

Comment: Thank you for the tips, Eugene. I will try them out.